# Forged Carbon Material

Tags: materials, shaders

Maybe someone can help me. I've been trying for some time now to get Forged Carbon as realistic a texture as possible. Are there shaders that can be combined, or do I have to create an image texture? How do I get some parts to gloss and reflect and others to be matt?

Thank you in advance :)

[image]

Comment: You could try using an image texture with the principled shader.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you could do it procedurally, but if you want to use an image texture you could go this way:

- Unwrap your object with the *Smart UV Project* mode. Give it a black image texture.

[image]

- Switch to *Texture Paint* mode, load a forged carbon image texture, choose *Brush Mapping* > *Stencil* (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> to move, <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Maj</kbd> to scale, <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to rotate), paint the surface of your object, it will paint over your black image.

[image]

- Mix your image texture with a *Glossy* node, play with the *Glossy* value and the *Mix* factor.

[image]

- If the glossiness depends on the grey value, use the image as a factor in the *Mix* factor. I don't know forged carbon but you might also want to play with *Clearcot*, in that case use a *Principled* instead of a *Diffuse*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: final]

You can use simple "stacking/layering" to make it procedurally.

Basically I've used only **Noise Texture** with different Scale, Distortion, Detail and different Colour Ramps.

You can add more "layers" of noise to have even better result.

[image: nodes]

> Note: Noise Texture node is from master build but using currently
>   available in official release changes almost nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try the layering. How can i add the "lighten" shader and the first option at the Noise Texture (W)? :)

Comment: @NikLeo Oh darn, which version are you using? I'm building master daily and have just lost track what options are merged into official builds. You can skip 'W' option. Lighten is Color > MixRGB then choose Lighten.

Comment: i´m using 2.8. Thank you

Comment: @NikLeo it's not that simple any more. We have 2.80 official, 2.81 beta and 2.82 (master) alpha :D

Comment: i´m using v2.80.58. Works really good with the layering . Can I make some of the Noise textures glossy and some matte?

Comment: @NikLeo Yes, for this I've used Color Ramp connected to Roughness.